# multiple mysql tables with multiple joins

Tags: mysql

I have 4 mysql tables as follows:

```
products:
----------------------------------------------------
product_id    product_name   price    discount
----------------------------------------------------
1             product 1      10.00       1.00
2             product 2      20.00       2.00
3             product 3      25.00       1.00
----------------------------------------------------

subcategory

----------------------------------------------------
cb_category_id    subcategory_name       status
----------------------------------------------------
   1                 subcat 1            Enabled
   2                 subcat 2            Disabled
   3                 subcat 3            Enabled
------------------------------------------------------

temp_products
------------------------------------------------------
id               productid               catid
------------------------------------------------------
1                   1                      1
2                   1                      2
3                   2                      1
------------------------------------------------------

product_images
------------------------------------------------------
product_id                images
------------------------------------------------------
   1                    image1.jpg
   1                    image2.jpg
   2                    image2-1.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------
```

temp_products.catid and subcategory.cb_category_id

and

temp_products.productid and products.product_id

and

products.product_id and product_images.product_id

are related..A product can have multiple images.

I wish to have a subcategory selected with all products with first image for a product from product_images and WHERE subcategory.status is "Enabled"...?? Need to limit output to only 1 cb_category_id with multiple product_id under it, like as follows:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cb_category_id   subcategory_name product_id  product_name, price, discount, images
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1              subcat 1           1        product 1    10.00   1.00    image1.jpg
     1              subcat 1           2        product 2    20.00   2.00    image2- 1.jpg
```

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT p.product_id,p.product_name,p.price,p.discount,s.cb_category_id,s.subcategory_name 
FROM products p,subcategory s
INNER JOIN temp_products ON p.product_id = temp_products.productid
INNER JOIN temp_products tp ON tp.catid = s.cb_category_id
WHERE tp.catid = s.cb_category_id
```

I am getting unknown column p.product_id in on clause ....Regarding including images i am at a dead end.
Help requested...I am unable to comprehend the joins required for the same...

Comment: @Unihedron sorry, it was an error while typing..I get the error "unknown column p.product_id in on clause"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a typo . you dont have products_id in your products table.

change this

```
  p.products_id
```

to

```
  p.product_id
```

EDIT: rewrite your query like that :

```
  SELECT  p.product_id,p.product_name,p.price,p.discount,s.cb_category_id,s.subcategory_name ,pi.images
  FROM products p
  INNER JOIN temp_products tp ON p.product_id = tp.productid
  INNER JOIN product_images pi ON p.product_id = pi.product_id
  INNER JOIN subcategory s ON tp.catid = s.cb_category_id
  GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Comment: Sorry, it was an error while typing. I still get the same error "unknown column p.product_id in on clause"

Comment: have added product_images table and group by , try that now.

Comment: images are not getting displayed in the row..Moreover the processing is taking too much time.

Comment: is not getting displaying because you are not selecting them , i will edit.

Comment: images was missing in the select...How can we optimize the query to make it fast...taking too much time ??

Comment: well glad it worked for you now , about optimisation this query is simple . you have to ask question about it and share your table shema and all .

Comment: product_id in products table is already indexed being the Primary key. The query is taking 19.851 secs to execute ??

Comment: Optimisation is other question dude . and you have to share your tables shema and structure .

Comment: GROUP BY is taking too much time...Thank you very much for your answer..may god bless you..I will post another question regarding schema..

Answer (score 0):

Your `'temp_products'` table is basically a mapping table for `'products' and 'subcategory'`. I have not tested the following code but you'll get the idea from comments(text after # character). this should solve your problem:

```
SELECT p.product_id,p.product_name,p.price,p.discount,s.cb_category_id,s.subcategory_name,pim.images
FROM products p
INNER JOIN temp_products tp ON p.product_id = tp.productid          #remove duplicate join
INNER JOIN subcategory s ON tp.catid = s.cb_category_id
LEFT JOIN product_images pim ON pim.product_id =p.product_id        #join for images
WHERE s.status = 'Enabled' AND                                      #subcategory is enabled
s.cb_category_id = '1'                                              #subcategory you want to be selected
GROUP BY p.product_id ORDER BY p.product_id, pim.images;
```